# creating/deleting temp files (names at array)

Tags: bash, shell, for

Hello I'm want to create temp files and then delete them. I have name of variables in ARRAY.
Creating is working but I have problems with delete them.
Thanks

```
FILES=( a b c d e f g h)

for i in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    eval "$i"=`mktemp`
done
```

Comment: Doesn't the `rm` command work?

Answer (score 2):

If your bash shell is new enough (version 4+), then I would recommend using an associative array to store the filenames:

```
declare -A filenames
for i in "${FILES[@]}"; do
  filenames[$i]=$(mktemp)
done
```

Then it's easy to remove them when you're done:

```
rm -- "${filenames[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd want:

```
file_variables=(a b c d e f g h)
files=()
for var in "${file_variables[@]}"; do
  file=$(mktemp) || exit
  eval "$var=\$file"
  files+=("$file") # or files=("${files[@]}" "$file") with older versions
done

something with "$a"
something with "$g"...

rm -f -- "${files[@]}"
```

Pay attention to quoting. For instance, you should not pass the expansion of `$(mktemp)` to `eval`, but the literal `$(mktemp)` string instead. In `bash`, you need to quote most expansions as well.

The only ones we're note quoting are the `a=$file`, `b=$file` that are run by `eval` above, as the split+glob doesn't (cannot) happen in assignment to scalar variables. The quotes are needed for assignments to array variables like in our `files+=("$file")`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to create a TEMP directory, then create the temporary files in the TEMP directory.  That way you can delete all files in the temp directory without worry using something like

```
rm ./TEMP/*
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need design of commands like at desscription.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a nameref (Bash 4+)

```
declare -a names=( a b c d e )

for n in "${names[@]}"; do
  declare -n ref="$n"
  ref="$( mktemp )"
done

for n in "${names[@]}"; do
  declare -n ref="$n"
  test -f "$ref" && rm "$ref"
done
```

A nameref is a variable that has been declared using `declare -n` (or `local -n`, or `typeset -n`). The name of another variable is assigned to it upon declaring it as a nameref. After that point, using the value of the nameref variable is the same as using the value of the variable named when creating the nameref.